# Trying to render preloaded images with jsx (next.js)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

basically I'm trying to make one of those apple scroll  image animations: [example](https://css-tricks.com/lets-make-one-of-those-fancy-scrolling-animations-used-on-apple-product-pages/)
I can see on my network dev tools that the images are preloaded but I'm not sure how to render them with my jsx

this is how i'm preloading them

```js
  useEffect(()=>{
    const preloadImages = () => {
      const emptyArray = [...Array(frameCount+1).keys()]
      emptyArray.forEach((element)=>{
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = `/image-sequence/animation (${element}).png`;
      })
    }
    preloadImages();
  },[])
```

and this is how i'm rendering them

```js
<img
  src={`/image-sequence/animation (${frame}).png`}
  alt='sososowhat'
  className='h-auto max-w-6xl w-full'
/>
```

when i look at my network tag it fetches the required photo again rather than making use of the preloaded photo

Comment: Using the native `Image` element of NextJS, you should be able to fetch them with the proper priority. https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image. If you want all of them prefetched, then you might consider keeping the component as a `server component`.

Comment: Create an image state and set initial value to null. and when image load set the state. show your image using condition if state is null hide otherwise show. May be you have to set background color until image is loading.